# MySQL Update value line per line depending on condition

Tags: mysql, conditional-statements

I have a DB (I'm running MySQL 5.7) with two tables containing data about mechanical assemblies and their inventory. To know about their availability, the availability of one key component is crucial. The stock of the key component is in the second table (attribute1).

```
Table: assemblies_details
id   name       stock 
1    assembly1  ?
2    assembly2  ?
3    item1      1
4    item2      2

Table: assemblies_attributes
id   name       attribute1
1    assembly1  item1
2    assembly2  item2
3    item1      
4    item2
```

The stock for the items is updated automatically. For now, the key component is manually set for each assembly in the `attribute1` field. I'm looking for a way to update `stock` for each assembly by checking `stock` of the item stated in `attribute1` and writing the related `stock` value into the line of the assembly.

So far my biggest problem is finding a way to have `UPDATE` change line after line by searching for the in `attribute1` stated item and copying the existing `stock` value. 
As my experience with MySQL is very limited I have only found a way to use `UPDATE` to change values after checking for a simple condition (something written in `attribute1`):

```
UPDATE assemblies_details
SET attribute1 = CASE
  WHEN LENGTH(assemblies_details.attribute1) > 0 THEN ???
  ELSE NULL
END
```

Is the query I'm trying to build feasible at all or am I missing something?
So far the code I have in my head would search the whole database for each line over again. Is there a faster, more elegant way to realize what I'm trying to do?
Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for

```sql
UPDATE assemblies_details ad
  JOIN assemblies_attributes aa ON ad.name = aa.name
  JOIN assemblies_details ad2 ON aa.attribute1 = ad2.name
SET ad.stock = COALESCE(ad.stock, ad2.stock);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cedd07ecd5dddd61f1607077dec31479)